# Database change detection process in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm trying to design a process to capture database change detection and then push it to GitHub. Trying to explore the free options or write a custom code. Few options that i have thought about:

1. Create a hierarchy folder structure like Account-->Db-->schema-->table,views,sp etc (different folders) being tracked by GitHub and export all the objects every time we want to push code to GitHub.
   GitHub will track all the changes(any new objects or updates). Haven't thought about the deletes.
2. Write code inside snowflake that detects changes (using full outer join) in objects and then writes the data in a table in Snowflake which includes the latest DDL.

Can anyone help me out with something similar any one has used to implement database change detection in Snowflake. I have seen DBT, Sqitch and snowchange but they doesn't fit/suit what i'm trying to do.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "capture database change detection". Do you mean changes to the DDL (structure and objects) or changes to the data or both?

Comment: Only changes to DDL (Structure and objects). Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider using terraform with its provider https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/terraform-provider-snowflake. Terraform is a tool for building, changing, and versioning infrastructure safely and efficiently, with Snowflake provider you can create DB, table, schemas, pipes, version them in Github, and deploy the changes to Snowflake. We are planning to use it for what you mentioned. The boring part is that in the beginning, we have to import a lot of existing resources, but after this is done, and we have everything in Github, we can introduce CI/CD, means that we change the code first in Github via a Pull request, then when reviewed, and approved, on merge to master the changes will be propagated to Snowflake, and it works also for deleting resources.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I had a look at the link but not very confident if we could implement it.